# VBScript Renaming Windows Computer with Options

Tags: windows, vbscript, rename

You guys did great helping me with one VBScript, so I'm going to throw another your way. Perhaps you can help me iron out the wrinkles.

My intention with this script is to rename the PC. The computer name is a combination of prompted text (something I provide, say a location code), a hyphen, and the last 10 digits of the computer's serial number called from WMIC. i.e. 1275-XXXXXXXXXX

My problems here are the following:

1. If my code is over 10 characters, it just errors out. I want to fix
   that. I'm sure it's just the way I have it coded and nothing to do
   with pulling from WMIC.
2. If it does error out pulling the serial number from WMIC, say because there's no value, I want to be prompted to enter something in it's place. Then at the end it will take Input1 (the location code) and Input2 (what I provide if the SN pull fails), smack a hyphen in the middle, and apply it.
3. My error out isn't working if it does fail. I don't know why.

I've found so many different solutions for renaming PC's either what I type in or specifically for pulling the SN, but not for my specific situation. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, as always. :)

Here's my code:

```
'Rename computer by serial # v1.0 November 2009
dim Bios, BiosSerial, objFSO, objTextFile
'Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

'get PropertyID
strInput = UserInput( "Enter the BHMS Property ID:" )

Function UserInput( myPrompt )
' This function prompts the user for some input.
' When the script runs in CSCRIPT.EXE, StdIn is used,
' otherwise the VBScript InputBox( ) function is used.
' myPrompt is the the text used to prompt the user for input.
' The function returns the input typed either on StdIn or in InputBox( ).
' Written by Rob van der Woude
' http://www.robvanderwoude.com
' Check if the script runs in CSCRIPT.EXE
If UCase( Right( WScript.FullName, 12 ) ) = "\CSCRIPT.EXE" Then
    ' If so, use StdIn and StdOut
    WScript.StdOut.Write myPrompt & " "
    UserInput = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
Else
    ' If not, use InputBox( )
    UserInput = InputBox( myPrompt )
End If
End Function

'Obtain Serial Number.
for each Bios in GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf ("win32_bios")
BiosSerial = Bios.SerialNumber
exit for
next

strNewSN = BiosSerial

' If the SN is longer than 10 characters, truncate to the last 10.
If Len(strNewSN) < 9 Then
    strNewSN = Right(BiosSerial, 10)
    strNewPCName = strInput+"-"+strNewSN
End If

Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colComputers = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

For Each objComputer in colComputers
err = objComputer.Rename(strNewPCName)

if err <> 0 then
wscript.echo "There was an error renaming the PC. Please restart and try again, or rename it manually."
else
wscript.echo "PC successfully renamed: " & strNewPCName
end if

Next
```

**5/29/2013 EDIT: I've made some changes based on your suggestion, and I'm getting on error on line 36 char 1 "Expected Statement" Code 800A0400. It looks fine to me so what am I missing? Here's a new paste of my code with line 36 notated.**

```
dim Bios, BiosSerial, objFSO, objTextFile
'Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

' Prompt for PropertyID
strInput = UserInput( "Enter the BHMS Property ID:" )

Function UserInput( myPrompt )
    ' Check if the script runs in CSCRIPT.EXE
    If UCase( Right( WScript.FullName, 12 ) ) = "\CSCRIPT.EXE" Then
        ' If so, use StdIn and StdOut
        WScript.StdOut.Write myPrompt & " "
        UserInput = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
    Else
        ' If not, use InputBox( )
        UserInput = InputBox( myPrompt )
    End If
End Function

' Obtain Serial Number.
for each Bios in GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf ("win32_bios")
BiosSerial = Bios.SerialNumber
exit for
next

strNewSN = BiosSerial

If IsEmpty(BiosSerial) Then
  strNewSN = UserInput("There is no serial number listed in the BIOS. Provide an alternative: ")
Else
  strNewSN = BiosSerial
End If

' If the SN is longer than 10 characters, truncate to the last 10.
If Len(strNewSN) > 10 Then strNewSN = Right(BiosSerial, 10)
strNewPCName = strInput & "-" & strNewSN
End If                                                           'LINE36'

Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colComputers = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

For Each objComputer in colComputers
err = objComputer.Rename(strNewPCName)

On Error <> 0 Then
wscript.echo "There was an error renaming the PC. Please restart and try again, or rename it manually."
Else
wscript.echo "PC successfully renamed: " & strNewPCName
end if

    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If my code is over 10 characters, it just errors out. I want to fix that. I'm sure it's just the way I have it coded and nothing to do with pulling from WMIC.*

```
' If the SN is longer than 10 characters, truncate to the last 10.
If Len(strNewSN) < 9 Then
  strNewSN = Right(BiosSerial, 10)
  strNewPCName = strInput+"-"+strNewSN
End If
```

Your comment says that you want to use the last 10 characters from the serial number if the serial number is longer than that, but your code takes the last 10 characters only if the serial number is shorter than **9** characters. Change that into

```
If Len(strNewSN) > 10 Then strNewSN = Right(BiosSerial, 10)
strNewPCName = strInput & "-" & strNewSN
```

> *If it does error out pulling the serial number from WMIC, say because there's no value, I want to be prompted to enter something in it's place. Then at the end it will take Input1 (the location code) and Input2 (what I provide if the SN pull fails), smack a hyphen in the middle, and apply it.*

You could use `IsEmpty()` to check if the `BiosSerial` variable has a value:

```
If IsEmpty(BiosSerial) Then
  strNewSN = UserInput("Enter fake serial number:")
Else
  strNewSN = BiosSerial
End If
```

> *My error out isn't working if it does fail. I don't know why.*

Define "isn't working". What result do you get, and how is it different from the result you expect?

BTW, you shouldn't use `err` as a name for a variable. [`Err`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf5ze0e) is an intrinsic object that VBScript provides in the context of [handling terminating errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h).

---

**Edit:** You have a spurious `End If` in line 36:

```
If Len(strNewSN) > 10 Then strNewSN = Right(BiosSerial, 10)
strNewPCName = strInput & "-" & strNewSN
End If
```

Remove that line and the error will disappear.

In VBSCript an `If` statement can have two forms:

- With closing `End If`:

  ```
  If condition Then
    instruction
  End If
  ```

  When using this form, `instruction` **must not** be on the same line as the `Then` keyword.
- Without closing `End If`:

  ```
  If condition Then instruction
  ```

  When using this form, `instruction` **must** be on the same line as the `Then` keyword and **must not** be followed by an `End If`.

In line 34 of your code you truncate the serial number to 10 characters if it's longer than that, and then execute the next line regardless of whether the serial number had to be truncated or not (that line must be executed unconditionally, so I removed it from the `Then` branch):

```
If Len(strNewSN) > 10 Then strNewSN = Right(BiosSerial, 10)
strNewPCName = strInput & "-" & strNewSN
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
If Len(strNewSN) > 10 Then
  strNewSN = Right(BiosSerial, 10)
End If
strNewPCName = strInput & "-" & strNewSN
```

Comment: I posted a new snippet of code in my edit. Could you take a look and see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks so much for your help and insight! :)